# Combing two views with different models

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4

Hi all i'm not sure how to do this. I have two views with 2 separate models, i would like to combine the 2, so that they are both on one view.

View 1:

```
@model IEnumerable<TelephoneNumberManagement.Models.Range>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            RangeName
        </th>
        <th>
            RangeNumber
        </th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink(item.RangeName, "ViewSubRange", new { id = item.ID })
        </td>
        <td>
            @item.RangeNumber
        </td>
    </tr>
}
</table>
```

View 2:-

```
@model IEnumerable<TelephoneNumberManagement.Models.TestNumber>
<h2>Index</h2>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            Number
        </th>
        <th>
            Status
        </th>
        <th>
            Customer
        </th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr> 
        <td>@item.Number</td>
        <td>@item.Status.StatusName</td>
        <td>@item.CustomerID</td>
    </tr> 

}
</table>
```

HomeController:-

```
public ViewResult Index()
{
  return View(context.Ranges.ToList().OrderBy(m => m.RangeName));
}

public ActionResult ViewSubRange(int id)
{
  IEnumerable<TestNumber> testNumbersList = context.TestNumbers.Where(m => m.RangeID == id).ToList();

  return View("SubRange", testNumbersList);
}
```

Any help would be really appreciated as i'm banging my head against the wall with this!!

Comment: I use partial views for this task. @Html.RenderPartial("_SharedViewName") AS far as ViewModels are concerned it gets a bit more tricky. If you are going to have several partial views on the page you can have what a call a master view model class that contains the other view models.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take your two views and put them into partials (if you still need the original views have them also use the partials so your views are defined in one place -- the partials). For your "both in one view", add a new action and a model that has an instance of each model needed for the partials.

Model:

```
public class MyBothInOneModel
{
    public ModelA modelA { get; set; }
    public ModelB modelB { get; set; }
}
```

Action:

```
public ViewResult BothInOne(int idForB)
{
    MyBothInOneModel m = new MyBothInOneModel();
    m.modelA = context.Ranges.ToList().OrderBy(m => m.RangeName));
    m.modelB = context.TestNumbers.Where(m => m.RangeID == idForB).ToList();
}
```

View - add a view with a call to render partial for each:

```
...
     Html.RenderPartial(Model.modelA, "PartialA");
     Html.RenderPartial(Model.modelB, "PartialB");
...
```

Or you can use ViewData/ViewBag to avoid creating MyBothInOneModel class.

Comment: I started with no answers! Almost worth having a copy & paste for this question.

Answer (score 1):

You have a bunch of options. First you can create a ViewModel having a property

`IEnumerable<TelephoneNumberManagement.Models.TestNumber> TestNumbers`

and a property

`IEnumerable<TelephoneNumberManagement.Models.Range> Ranges`

and then return a view, binding to the new ViewModel and using the combined data.

As an alternative (imho smarter solution) you could render each view as a child view `@Html.Action("ActionForView1")` and `@Html.Action("ActionForView2")`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ViewModel pattern to solve this.  Create a "ViewModel" that combines all the different models and/or presentation logic you need for a given view.

e.g.:

```
class TelephoneViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<TelephoneNumberManagement.Models.TestNumber> { get; set;}
    public IEnumerable<TelephoneNumberManagement.Models.Range> { get; set; }
}
```

Then let your new combined view use the ViewModel for it's model.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a basic example of what I am talking about.

```
 public class LoginRegisterMemberViewModel
{
    public OpenIdLoginViewModel OpenIdLoginViewModel { get; set; }
    public SiteLoginViewModel SiteLoginViewModel { get; set; }
    public RegisterMemberViewModel RegisterMemberViewModel { get; set; }
    public string ReturnUrl { get; set; }
}
```

On my Login View I user @model Web.ViewModels.LoginRegisterMemberViewModel

The partial views also use @model Web.ViewModels.LoginRegisterMemberViewModel
So now I have access to LoginRegsiterMemberViewModel.SiteLoginViewModel.property etc..

Hope this is not totally off base from what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I suppose I need to learn to cut and paste faster LOL... both answers work.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use a dynamic variable for your views

```
@model IEnumerable<dynamic>
```

Then you could send any model you want to the view, but you would need to be wise about what properties to use.

Answer (score 0):

Also a good option, if you wish to obtain clean separation, is to use Html.RenderAction from a main view. Then implement to separate controllers for each of the views described.